# NHibernate update on single property updates all properties in sql

Tags: sql, nhibernate, sql-update

I am performing a standard update in NHibernate to a single property. However on commit of the transaction the sql update seems to set all fields I have mapped on the table even though they have not changed. Surely this can't be normal behaviour in Nhibernate? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
           {
               using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
               {
                   var singleMeeting = session.Load<Meeting>(10193);
                   singleMeeting.Subject = "This is a test 2";

                   transaction.Commit();
               }
           }
```

Comment: just encountered the same situation. I think this is a bad default and I will look for online discussions in the appropriate forums. this has caused bugs in a server application I'm working on - since it changes application logic, typically in cases of concurrent actions where an object is created, then fetched, fetched by another thread/process (different session), modified and updated (updating separate non related fields). the last update will run over the changes in the previous transaction...
I've consulted this with my colleagues and we think the performance gain isn't drastic.

Comment: @YonatanKarni, this not only about performance but also about consistency. See this [question](/q/13954882/1178314), and its [currently accepted answer](/a/13955305/1178314).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the normal behavior. You can try adding `dynamic-update="true"` to your class definition to override this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Well. yes this is normal behaviour for NHibernate. You can use generated attribute for your properties to change the behaviour. Details on [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/07/nhibernate-mapping-ltpropertygt.aspx).

Why is this default is because with dynamics you don't get your query plan cached. And usually you don't mind that you send few more bytes over high speed network connection between your application server and database. Unless you are saving long strings where this setting is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: While Generated means that the field will not be sent in through an update, it also means that the field is handled server-side.  Instead NabilS is looking for those fields to be sent that have changed.

Comment: Actually that blog post does not give the required details, as it relates to the Property level. @Darin's answer is at the class level, which is where you want can change this behaviour.